PostgreSQL (AWS Redshift) Forward-fill null values based on previous non-null value in the same column
I have the following dataset:
create schema m;
create table m.parent_child_lvl_1(customer_id,date,order_type,order_id,sub_id)
as values
 (108384372,'18/09/2023'::date,'sub_parent_first_order',5068371361861,407284605)
,(108384372, '13/11/2023', 'sub_order', 5134167539781, null)
,(108384372, '8/01/2024', 'sub_order', 5214687526981, null)
,(108384372, '4/03/2024', 'sub_order', 5283166126149, null)
,(108384372, '18/06/2024', 'sub_parent_order', 5421811138629, 500649255)
,(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_order', 5508433641541, null)
,(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_order', 5508433641541, null);

I need to fill the null's with the Sub_ID until it hits the next non-null Sub_ID, then fill until the next, and so on.
The null order only works based on the Date ordering.
Also, needs to be grouped by Customer_ID. The full dataset has 15M rows, so any speed optimisation would be a bonus.
I've tried lead(), lag(), lastvalue(), coalesce() but the closest I got was only filling in the first null value after each real value.
The closest I've come to is this:
SELECT
  first_value(sub_id) OVER (
    PARTITION BY customer_id, value_partition 
    ORDER BY customer_id, date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS parent_sub_id,
  customer_id,
  order_id
FROM (
  SELECT
customer_id,
order_id,
sub_id,
date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sub_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (
      ORDER BY customer_id, date 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS value_partition
from m.parent_child_lvl_1 
where customer_id in ('227330109','90872199','102694972')
and
order_type in (
'sub_parent_first_order',
'sub_parent_order',
'sub_order'
)
  ORDER BY date ASC
) AS q
ORDER BY customer_id, date
 ;

Which seems to work for some records, but then goes wrong for others and I can't figure out why.
Edit:  Here is a screenshot of the result set, with the column A returning actuals, and column B is what i actually need.


i thought i figured it out and posted an answer, but i hadnt. :(  so i deleted the wrong answer. if anyone knows how, please lemme know :P

It would be great if you showed examples of how it "goes wrong for others". As a side-note, this sort of thing can also be done using self-joins, correlated scalar and lateral subqueries.

Can you give an example of the expected result?

Edit'ed original question with a second screenshot - adding expected result

@Maz Please paste that as text, along with input data that the query is supposed to process into this expected result.

@Maz Can sub_parent_first_order be null? Is this a bug?

I suspect your "what I need" column doesn't show what you actually need, instead showing something close to what you tried and did not work: it's forward-filling the subscription_id 275537132 from customer 102694972 to a completely unrelated customer 227330109 because of how you set up your window. I've addressed that in my initial answer. Please, replace pictures of text with actual text and clarify your logic.

A shorter alternative, using Redshift ignore nulls option (not available in PostgreSQL):

IGNORE NULLS
The function returns the last value in the frame that is not NULL (or NULL if all values are NULL).

select*,last_value(sub_id) ignore nulls
          over(partition by customer_id
               order by date
               rows between unbounded preceding 
                        and current_row) as forward_filled_sub_id
from m.parent_child_lvl_1 
where customer_id in (  '108384372','222222222','333333333','444444444'
                      , '555555555','666666666','777777777','888888888' )
  and order_type in (  'sub_parent_first_order'
                     , 'sub_parent_order'
                     , 'sub_order')
order by customer_id
       , date
       , order_id;


Your method doesn't seem wrong but it might be handling strange cases in a way you didn't expect it to:

The window definition in your subquery is missing a partition by. The fact that customer_id is on the first position of its order by helps because different customers are never in the same peer group.
Thing is, it's overlooking the fact that higher customer_id's see
all preceding customers. This means a series of orders with a
leading null would fall back on sub_id from some completely
unrelated customer with a lower identifier.

Your outer query window frame spec is too narrow. If there are multiple orders from the same customer and date, some null and some not, only one of them will have the full picture to be able to pick one of the not-null values. You can fix it by expanding it to unbounded following.

The outer query window only needs to be ordered by sub_id nulls last. You already established sub-partitions with at most a single not-null in them, now you just need to make sure it comes first if you want first_value() to pick it up.
Even though Redshift Unsupported PostgreSQL features lists this:

NULLS clause in Window functions

I don't think they mean nulls last|first because it's clearly in Redshift window function syntax:

The order_list is as follows.
expression | column_name [ ASC | DESC ] 
[ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST ]
[, order_list ]


But even if the clause doesn't work, if you get rid of it the null values should come last by default:

By default, NULL values are sorted and ranked last in ASC ordering

Unlike in PostgreSQL, there's also an option to ignore nulls in Redshift, which saves you the whole nested window function call.


demo at db<>fiddle
select*,first_value(sub_id)
          over(partition by customer_id, value_partition 
               order by sub_id nulls last
               rows between unbounded preceding 
                        and unbounded following) as forward_filled_sub_id
from(select customer_id
          , order_id
          , sub_id
          , date
          , count(sub_id)
              over(partition by customer_id
                   order by date, order_id, sub_id nulls last
                   rows between unbounded preceding 
                            and current row) as value_partition
     from m.parent_child_lvl_1 
     where customer_id in (  '108384372','222222222','333333333','444444444'
                           , '555555555','666666666','777777777','888888888' )
     and order_type in (  'sub_parent_first_order'
                        , 'sub_parent_order'
                        , 'sub_order')
    ) as subquery
order by customer_id
       , date
       , order_id;


You can do this sort of thing:
SUM(CASE WHEN sub_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)

a bit more efficiently using an aggregate filter clause:
count(*)filter(where sub_id is not null)

But for this particular use case, there's a dedicated variant of count():
count(sub_id)


count ( "any" ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows in which the input value is not null.

The count(expression) is available in both PostgreSQL and Redshift but unfortunately Redshift doesn't seem to support the filter clause. It offers a qualify, but that filters things going out of the function, not what's fed into it.

Whenever your window has an ORDER BY, the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is implied in PostgreSQL:

The default framing option is RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING, which is the same as RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW. With ORDER BY, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition start up through the current row's last ORDER BY peer.

Unfortunately, that's not the case in Redshift:

If an ORDER BY clause is used for an aggregate function, an explicit frame clause is required.


Defining the window in its dedicated section instead of right in over() lets you re-use the same window definition multiple times and tidies up the select section a bit. You can also base other windows off of pre-defined windows: demo at db<>fiddle
select item_id
     , item_category
     , sum(weight)over w1 as "total weight in its category"
     , sum(volume)over w1 as "total volume in its category"
     , sum(weight)over(w1 order by date) as "stepping weight in its category" 
from test
window w1 as (partition by item_category);

Unfortunately, Redshift doesn't support it.



Assuming that your actual data could be ordered like in the sample data provided and with order_ids and sub_ids that are ascending with dates and transactions (they most probably are):



customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
sub_id




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
null


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
null


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
null


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null



... you could use Max() Over() analytic function partitioned by customer_id and ordered by date and (within the same date) by order_id with windowing clause looking at all previous rows and the current row:
--      S Q L : 
Select    p.*,
          Max( sub_id ) OVER( Partition By customer_id  
                                Order By date, order_id
                                  Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row 
                            ) as parent_sub_id
From     parent_child_lvl_1 p
Where    customer_id IN('108384372','123123123') And 
         order_type in (  'sub_parent_first_order', 'sub_parent_order', 'sub_order')
Order By customer_id, date, order_id;

... Resulting as:



customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
sub_id
parent_sub_id




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605
407284605


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
null
407284605


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
null
407284605


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
null
407284605


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null
500649255



If there is a possibility of mixed null and not null values of sub_id column of sub orders within the customer_id's date ordered window



customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
sub_id




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
null


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
null


108384372
2024-02-01
sub_order
5241656510881
666777888


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
null


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null



... then the Max() Over() analytic function should be defined conditionaly:
--      S Q L : 
Select    p.*,
          Coalesce( sub_id, 
                    Max( Case When order_type IN('sub_parent_first_order', 'sub_parent_order') 
                              Then sub_id 
                         End ) OVER( Partition By customer_id  
                                       Order By date, order_id
                                       Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row 
                                   ) 
                  ) as parent_sub_id
From     parent_child_lvl_1 p
Where    customer_id IN('108384372','123123123') And 
         order_type in (  'sub_parent_first_order', 'sub_parent_order', 'sub_order')
Order By customer_id, date, order_id;

... the existing sub_id of sub_order type will remain intact and null values will be replaced with parent_sub_id ...
Result:



customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
sub_id
parent_sub_id




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605
407284605


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
null
407284605


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
null
407284605


108384372
2024-02-01
sub_order
5241656510881
666777888
666777888


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
null
407284605


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null
500649255



See the fiddle here.

Try this option

Case when sub_parent_first_order cannot be null

select * from orders_table order by date;

 customer_id |    date    | sub_id |       order_type
-------------+------------+--------+------------------------
        2222 | 2023-01-10 |        | non_sub_first_order
        2222 | 2023-04-10 |   3257 | sub_parent_first_order
        2222 | 2023-05-10 |        | non_sub_order
        2222 | 2023-06-10 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2023-09-18 |   9093 | sub_parent_first_order
        1234 | 2023-10-18 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-01-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-02-15 |   7676 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-03-15 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-04-15 |   4869 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-05-15 |   7490 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-06-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-07-15 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-08-15 |        | sub_order

select Customer_id,Date,
       case when Sub_id is NULL and left (order_type,3)<>'non' then 
       (select m1.Sub_ID from orders_table m1 
        where m1.Sub_ID is not null and m1.Customer_id=orders_table.Customer_id 
        and m1.Date<orders_table.Date
        order by m1.Date desc limit 1) 
       else Sub_id end,order_type  from orders_table order by Customer_ID,Date;

result:
 customer_id |    date    | sub_id |       order_type
-------------+------------+--------+------------------------
        1234 | 2023-09-18 |   9093 | sub_parent_first_order
        1234 | 2023-10-18 |   9093 | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-01-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-02-15 |   7676 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-03-15 |   7676 | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-04-15 |   4869 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-05-15 |   7490 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-06-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-07-15 |   7490 | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-08-15 |   7490 | sub_order
        2222 | 2023-01-10 |        | non_sub_first_order
        2222 | 2023-04-10 |   3257 | sub_parent_first_order
        2222 | 2023-05-10 |        | non_sub_order
        2222 | 2023-06-10 |   3257 | sub_order


Case when sub_parent_first_order can be null

select * from orders_table order by Customer_ID,Date;

 customer_id |    date    | sub_id |       order_type
-------------+------------+--------+------------------------
        1234 | 2020-09-18 |   9093 | sub_parent_first_order
        1234 | 2023-10-18 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-01-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-02-15 |   7676 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-03-15 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-04-15 |   4869 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-05-15 |   7490 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-06-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-07-15 |        | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-08-15 |        | sub_order
        2222 | 2023-01-10 |        | non_sub_first_order
        2222 | 2023-04-10 |        | sub_parent_first_order
        2222 | 2023-05-10 |        | non_sub_order
        2222 | 2023-06-10 |        | sub_order

select Customer_id,Date,
       case when Sub_id is NULL and left (order_type,3)<>'non' then 
       COALESCE ( (select m1.Sub_ID from orders_table m1 
                where m1.Sub_ID is not null and m1.Customer_id=orders_table.Customer_id 
                and m1.Date<orders_table.Date
                order by m1.Date desc limit 1), 
          (select m1.Sub_ID from orders_table m1 
            where m1.Sub_ID is not null 
            and m1.Customer_id<orders_table.Customer_id
            order by m1.Customer_id,m1.Date desc limit 1) )       
       else Sub_id end,order_type  from orders_table order by Customer_ID,Date;

results
 customer_id |    date    | sub_id |       order_type
-------------+------------+--------+------------------------
        1234 | 2020-09-18 |   9093 | sub_parent_first_order
        1234 | 2023-10-18 |   9093 | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-01-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-02-15 |   7676 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-03-15 |   7676 | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-04-15 |   4869 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-05-15 |   7490 | sub_parent_order
        1234 | 2024-06-15 |        | non_sub_order
        1234 | 2024-07-15 |   7490 | sub_order
        1234 | 2024-08-15 |   7490 | sub_order
        2222 | 2023-01-10 |        | non_sub_first_order
        2222 | 2023-04-10 |   7490 | sub_parent_first_order
        2222 | 2023-05-10 |        | non_sub_order
        2222 | 2023-06-10 |   7490 | sub_order


Thank you but that doesnt work, it is populating the field with incorrect sub_id's.
P.s.  The field isnt really called Date, I renamed for simplicity.

@Maz Hello, try again. This time the sub_id field should return the correct ID.

I suggest to include the order_id column in order by clause of window function .
For the case when there is an intersection or coincidence of rows by dates for a set of rows ('sub_parent_order', 'sub_orders'), order by date is insufficient.
You may be lucky, and adding order by date,order_id will help remove this uncertainty.
In my opinion, if you have direct links of child rows to parent rows - you need to use them.
See example
Some test data rows added.
create table parent_child_lvl_1(customer_id,date,order_type,order_id,sub_id)
as values
 (108384372,'18/09/2023'::date,'sub_parent_first_order',5068371361861,407284605)
,(108384372, '13/11/2023', 'sub_order', 5134167539781, null)
,(108384372, '8/01/2024', 'sub_order', 5214687526981, null)
,(108384372, '4/03/2024', 'sub_order', 5283166126149, null)
,(108384372, '18/06/2024', 'sub_parent_order', 5421811138629, 500649255)
,(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_order', 5508433641541, null)
,(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_order', 5508433641541, null)
,(108384372, '13/08/2024', 'sub_parent_order', 5528433650005, 500650005)

,(108384372, '14/08/2024', 'sub_parent_order', 5528433650004, 500650004)
;
insert into parent_child_lvl_1 values
(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_parent_order', 5521811150001, 500650001)
,(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_order', 5528433650002, null)
,(108384372, '12/08/2024', 'sub_order', 5528433650003, null)
;
select * from parent_child_lvl_1
order by customer_id,date,order_id  ;

I use 2 insert operation to complicate the certainty of the order of the rows.



customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
sub_id




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
null


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
null


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
null


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
null


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_parent_order
5521811150001
500650001


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5528433650002
null


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5528433650003
null


108384372
2024-08-13
sub_parent_order
5528433650005
500650005


108384372
2024-08-14
sub_parent_order
5528433650004
500650004



Query with order_id.
select customer_id, date,order_type,order_id
  ,max(sub_id)over(partition by customer_id,grn) new_sub_id
  ,sub_id old_sub_id, grn
from(
select t.*
  ,sum(case when sub_id is not null then 1 else 0 end)
     over(partition by customer_id order by date,order_id
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)grn
from parent_child_lvl_1 t
where customer_id in ('227330109','90872199','102694972','108384372')
   and t.order_type in ('sub_parent_first_order','sub_parent_order','sub_order')
)
order by customer_id,date,order_id ;




customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
new_sub_id
old_sub_id
grn




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605
407284605
1


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
407284605
null
1


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
407284605
null
1


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
407284605
null
1


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255
500649255
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
500649255
null
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
500649255
null
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_parent_order
5521811150001
500650001
500650001
3


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5528433650002
500650001
null
3


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5528433650003
500650001
null
3


108384372
2024-08-13
sub_parent_order
5528433650005
500650005
500650005
4


108384372
2024-08-14
sub_parent_order
5528433650004
500650004
500650004
5



And query without order_id.
select customer_id, date,order_type,order_id
  ,max(sub_id)over(partition by customer_id,grn) new_sub_id
  ,sub_id old_sub_id, grn
from(
select t.*
  ,sum(case when sub_id is not null then 1 else 0 end)
     over(partition by customer_id order by date
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)grn
from parent_child_lvl_1 t
where customer_id in ('227330109','90872199','102694972','108384372')
   and t.order_type in ('sub_parent_first_order','sub_parent_order','sub_order')
)
order by customer_id,date ;




customer_id
date
order_type
order_id
new_sub_id
old_sub_id
grn




108384372
2023-09-18
sub_parent_first_order
5068371361861
407284605
407284605
1


108384372
2023-11-13
sub_order
5134167539781
407284605
null
1


108384372
2024-01-08
sub_order
5214687526981
407284605
null
1


108384372
2024-03-04
sub_order
5283166126149
407284605
null
1


108384372
2024-06-18
sub_parent_order
5421811138629
500649255
500649255
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5528433650003
500649255
null
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
500649255
null
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5508433641541
500649255
null
2


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_parent_order
5521811150001
500650001
500650001
3


108384372
2024-08-12
sub_order
5528433650002
500650001
null
3


108384372
2024-08-13
sub_parent_order
5528433650005
500650005
500650005
4


108384372
2024-08-14
sub_parent_order
5528433650004
500650004
500650004
5



fiddle

Unfortunately, that's not valid as Redshift syntax.

Thank you. I can not chek just now in Redshift. What is error in syntax?
